# For loop in if clause. If clause is not calling

Tags: shell, if-statement, for-loop

I am new to the Shell, and trying to write few simple scripts.

Its not invoking `if` clause here or not calling `for` loop. I have shared the o/p

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
read -p "enter Date in DD " d
if [$d -gt "00" -a $d -lt "31"]
then
     echo "Choose any one month from given option: Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec"
     read  m
     for $m  in Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
      do
        case "echo $m" in
        Jan) mnum=01;;
        Feb) mnum=02;;
        Mar) mnum=03;;
        Apr) mnum=04;;
        May) mnum=05;;
        Jun) mnum=06;;
        Jul) mnum=07;;
        Aug) mnum=08;;
        Sep) mnum=09;;
        Oct) mnum=10;;
        Nov) mnum=11;;
        Dec) mnum=12;;
      esac
echo "Month is $mnum"
   done
else  echo "Its an invalid Date"
fi
    echo "Enter Year in YYYY"
     read y
   if echo $y |egrep "^[1|2][0-9][0-9]+$"
   then
    echo "Its Valid year"
    echo "Your date is $d/$m/$y"
   fi
~
```

**Output:**

```
 ./a.sh
+ read -p 'enter Date in DD ' d
enter Date in DD 23
+ '[23' -gt 00 -a 23 -lt '31]'
./a.sh: line 5: [23: command not found
+ echo 'Its an invalid Date'
Its an invalid Date
+ echo 'Enter Year in YYYY'
Enter Year in YYYY
+ read y
2015
+ echo 2015
+ egrep '^[1|2][0-9][0-9]+$'
2015
+ echo 'Its Valid year'
Its Valid year
+ echo 'Your date is 23//2015'
Your date is 23//2015
```

Comment: Indent the code and explain better the problem.

Comment: The main purpose is to take user input for date,month,year and times and print them in a specific format.But I want validations on the inputs.Like Date should be between 1 to 31,if it goes wrong then it will again invoke user for entering number .But I am not sure how to ask the user again for when validation fails

Comment: @Paulo Soares Can I get help here

Answer (score 0):

**1. If statement isuse:**

There is correction required for `if` statement, keep one `whitespace` between `[` and `$d` , also between `"31"` and `]`. 
Hemce correct if statement would be

```
if [ $d -gt "00" -a $d -lt "31" ]
```

Below is scriptlet and example output.

**Scriptlet:**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
read -p "enter Date in DD " d
if [ $d -gt "00" -a $d -lt "31" ]
then
    echo $d
fi
```

**Output:**

```
$ sh try.sh
+ read -p 'enter Date in DD ' d
enter Date in DD 21
+ '[' 21 -gt 00 -a 21 -lt 31 ']'
+ echo 21
21
```

**2. For Loop issue**

Your for loop is not syntactically correct. In for you can not use value (i.e. `$m`), instead you need to use variable (i.e. example `m`)
correct syntax : `for m in Jan Feb Mar Apr`

Comment: Thanks for guidance.

Comment: I want to use the value of  "m" which stored in previous read statement.How will I do that.

Comment: How do I repeat  the read statement   (read -p "enter Date in DD " d)                                      when if condition fails ( else  echo "Its an invalid Date").I want to ask the user for input again when the condition fails

Comment: @Nirmal , as commented by  Paulo Soares, could you please provide purpose of script?

Comment: The main purpose is to take user input for date,month,year and times and print them in a specific format.But I want validations on the inputs.Like Date should be between 1 to 31,if it goes wrong then it will again invoke user for entering number .But I am not sure how to ask the user again for when validation fails